# MS Excel - Add / Subtracting time in 0000 format

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, spreadsheet

I am trying to subtract time on Excel.

My company uses a 24hr time format (0500,0600, 1250, 1300 etc.)

I'm trying to calculate the time difference between 2 cells:

```
|  A1  |  B1  |
|------|------|
| 540  | 600  |
|      |      |
```

In cell C1 I have `=B2-A2` and it returns 60 which is technically correct but 5:40AM - 06:00AM is 20 minutes.

How do I go about making excel correctly calculate the time for me using this format?

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

Convert the numbers to time, subtract and convert the time returned to the correct format:

```
=--TEXT(REPLACE(TEXT(B1,"0000"),3,0,":")-REPLACE(TEXT(A1,"0000"),3,0,":"),"hhmm")
```

[image]

Comment: I think you can simplify that, eliminating the `REPLACE` function:  `=TEXT(TEXT(B1,"00\:00")-TEXT(A1,"00\:00"),"hhmm")`

Answer (score 0):

*There are several methods you can use to solve this issue. Shown below is one of them, to convert number to Hours and Minutes:*

[image]

- Formula in cell `E57`:

  ```
  =TEXT(TEXT(INT(B57/100)/24+MOD(B57,100)/1440,"hh:mm")-TEXT(INT(A57/100)/24+MOD(A57,100)/1440,"hh:mm"),"hh:mm")
  ```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*